# Julia: mapslices() where the function being mapped has multiple input arguments?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia, broadcast, array-broadcasting

I am trying to use `mapslices` (perhaps this isn't even the right approach) in a way that allows me to broadcast a function across the 'slices' of a multidimensional array, where the function involves another array that is always the same for each iteration of the broadcast. Can this be done with `mapslices` or `map`?

Here's the particular problem:

I have a function `F(X,Y)` that takes as input 2-Dimensional arrays `X` and `Y`. X is size `(D, N)` and has type = `Array{Float32,2}`), whereas Y is also of size `(D, 1)`, with type = `Array{Float32,2}`.

`F(X,Y)` performs an operation on the two matrices `X` and `Y` to yield an array output with size `(N, 1)`.

The broadcasting/mapping problem: I have a larger 3-D array `X_all` whose 'slices' (e.g. matrices stacked long the third dimension, like `X[:,:,1]`) are examples of input arrays X with dimensions `(D,N)`, that are supposed to be inputs to `F(X,Y)`. And `Y` is always constant.

So an example `X_all` would be of shape `(D, N, 5)`, with `Y` still being `(D,1)`, and I want the output of the broadcast to be a matrix whose columsn store the results of applying `F` to each slice of `X_all` and `Y`. So the final output shape in this example should be `(N,5)`.

This isn't working with `broadcast` (the error I get suggests that `F(X,Y)` is being fed scalar floating point numbers, not arrays), so I'm assuming it needs to be done with `mapslices`. The only issue is that I can't seem to find examples of `mapslices` being used with multiple input arguments (e.g. `X` and `Y`) -- usually I just see it with one input argument.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your written description of the problem is a little hard for me to follow, but if I understand the problem correctly, you just need to use `mapslices` with an anonymous function `X -> F(X, Y)`

Here's an example:

```
F(X, Y) = X'*Y 

F(rand(3, 4), rand(3, 1))

#+RESULTS:
: 4×1 Array{Float64,2}:
:  0.2038830017261133
:  0.16952327765859904
:  0.25986519462136687
:  0.18604863369789784
```

```
#+BEGIN_SRC jupyter-julia
let D = 3, N = 4
    x_all = randn(D, N, 5)
    Y = randn(D, 1)

    mapslices(X -> F(X, Y), x_all, dims=(1,2))
end

#+RESULTS:
4×1×5 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  1.949979259990055
  0.3939816492611507
 -0.8464390217323449
  0.4555254821129745

[:, :, 2] =
  1.6893553574839384
  1.9573396471517739
  1.5358035472026144
 -1.2706780393752082

[:, :, 3] =
  0.999887609119746
  0.32959013947652727
  0.8756560406754215
 -1.0257977117576802

[:, :, 4] =
 -0.2252063989697573
 -0.5968450960471975
 -0.7319338928241739
  0.236534278792568

[:, :, 5] =
 -0.9523913128029378
  0.13537059021324083
  0.9514285829484852
  0.5464547535310538
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about the anonymous function format -- thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: and just to quickly follow up -- if I wanted to drop that second singleton dimension from the output (whose size == 1), is the fastest way to use `dropdims(result, dims = 2)` ?

Comment: I believe so, yes.